# Azure Automation DSC: how to unregister old/misconfigured DSC Nodes from the pull server?

Tags: azure, dsc

Every now and then I am facing a situation where some old DSC Node remains on the registration list in the Azure Automation DSC pull server.

The nodes appear for a brief moment (1-2 seconds) after clicking on the DSC Nodes menu item (or tile) and disappear. I cannot access them otherwise. The number of DSC Nodes also includes those registrations.

[image]

[image]

The virtual machine on the screenshots does not exist anymore, adding a new one with the same name and in the same Resource Group creates a new registration entry.

How can I remove the old registrations (other than deleting and recreating the Automation Account)?

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, locate the DSC Node registration with:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureRmAutomationDscNode `
            -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
            -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName
```

Get the `Id` parameter (GUID) and unregister with:

```
PS C:\> Unregister-AzureRmAutomationDscNode `
            -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
            -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName `
            -Id xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```